# Using Entity Framework Code First approach, how do I create an entity that has a list of related entities as a child property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

## SOLVED!!!

Thanks to comments made by Gert below, I was able to solve.  I simply needed to attach my `Product` entities to the same context as the `Order` entity before saving the order:

```
public int Create(Order entity)
        {
            var order = entity;

            foreach (var product in order.Products)
            {
                db.Products.Attach(product);
            }

            db.Orders.Add(order);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return order.Id;
        }
```

## Original Post

Thanks for looking.  Here is my use case:

On an ecommerce application, I need to create an `Order`.  The `Order` has one or many `Product` entities as one of its properties.  Here are my two domain models:

### Order

```
 [Table("Order")]
    public class Order
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description.")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a trackingnumber.")]
        public string TrackingNumber { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an isactive.")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public int OrderStatusTypeId { get; set; }

        public virtual OrderStatusType OrderStatusType { get; set; }

        private ICollection<Product> _products;
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products
        {
            get { return _products ?? (_products = new Collection<Product>()); }
            set { _products = value; }
        }
    }
```

### Product

```
[Table("Product")]
    public class Product
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description.")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }


        private ICollection<Order> _orders;
        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders
        {
            get { return _orders ?? (_orders = new Collection<Order>()); }
            set { _orders = value; }
        }

        private ICollection<DeviceModel> _devicemodels;
        public virtual ICollection<DeviceModel> DeviceModels
        {
            get { return _devicemodels ?? (_devicemodels = new Collection<DeviceModel>()); }
            set { _devicemodels = value; }
        }
    }
```

Here is a look at a post object that the user has created:

```
{
  "Description": "Test description",
  "TrackingNumber": "12345",
  "Id": 1,
  "IsActive": true,
  "UserId": 0,
  "User": {
    "Email": "john@gmail.com",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "Id": 1,
    "LastName": "Doe"
  },
  "OrderStatusTypeId": 0,
  "OrderStatusType": {
    "Description": "The order is in processing.",
    "Id": 1,
    "Title": "Processing"
  },
  "Products": [{"Description":"Test product","Id":1,"Name":"Product A","DeviceModels":[]},{"Description":"Test","Id":2,"Name":"Product B","DeviceModels":[]}]
}
```

## Expected Behavior

When I `POST` this `Order` object to the server, I would have expected that a new order is created and the products belonging to that order would simply be referenced.

## Encountered Behavior

Each time I place an order, the related products are added a new products to the product table.  So, rather than having a few products that are referenced by several orders, I have several products with 1-to-1 relationship with the orders.

Here is what my Products table ends up looking like (note the repeated products):

[image]

## UPDATE

The Code First Approach **DOES** create a `ProductOrders` conjunction table for me, and it even adds the order and product ids to that table:

[image]

So why does it also add the products as new entities in the `Product` table rather than simply referencing the keys I pass to it?

Thanks in advance.

## UPDATE #1:

Here is my repository class for creating orders:

```
  public class OrderRepository : IRepository<Order, int>
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;

        public OrderRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            db = dbContext;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Creates and saves a new 'Order' entity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">The Order to save.</param>
        /// <returns>The id (int) of the newly created Order.</returns>
        public int Create(Order entity)
        {
            var order = entity;
            db.Orders.Add(order);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return order.Id;
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: This problem is as old as Entity Framework itself. Attach the products before adding the order.

Comment: Thank you Gert, but that is where I am getting lost.  Can you please provide a little bit of code to help me get some traction on that?  For example, do I create a new product object and then attach it to the new order and then commit to the db?  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: Gert!!  Thank you so much--you have made my weekend.  It works!  I will post the resolution for others.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the mappings for your collections. Here is an example using the fluent mapping interface.

```
public class OrderMapping:  EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
       public OrderMapping()
      {
         HasMany(o => o.Products).WithMany(p => p.Orders).Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("OrderId");
                m.MapRightKey("ProductId");
                m.ToTable("Order_Products");
            });
      }          
}
```

This will create a link table between Orders and Products.

Comment: Thanks, but even with this extra logic, additional Products continue to get added to the Product table.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt, What does your application code look like before the SaveChanges() method? How are the entities being created? Are you attaching the Products to the context then associating them with an order?

Comment: Thanks DDiVita--I have added a snippet of my Order Repo Class Above.